# Compile Shared DLL in MinGW using Static Libraries

Tags: dll, static, mingw, shared, msys

I am trying to create a single DLL for librsvg that does not require any other DLL and can be used within a MSVC application.  Using MinGW/MSYS I have compiled librsvg (and its 20 dependencies) and produced a DLL but all libraries are shared and ultimately I need 21 DLLs.  I have read and tried many dozens of articles and tried many different scenarios with the linker flag -static.  I have used --enable-static on all the dependencies and produced the .a static libraries for each.  However, I cannot seem to reach the end goal.  When compiling librsvg I can either produce the DLL with shared libraries or I can produce a shared library for it w/o creating a DLL - I cannot reach the goal of a single DLL.  I have also gone down the path of manually changing the makefile for librsvg and changing all the -l{library} lines to library.a and ultimately never got a clean compile due to issues with libtool.  If this is the correct path I will continue; however, it seems the entire purpose of libtool is to accomplish this goal w/o the need to modify the makefile.  Is there a better way?  Is this even possible?